# jquery tabs and sharepoint 2013 CQWP

Tags: jquery, content-query-web-part

I'm using Jquery tabs to display some contents from a content query webpart (used this article:http://www.sharemuch.com/2014/11/17/quickly-turning-your-content-query-web-part-display-into-a-jquery-tabs/).

My goal is to filter a content query web part using url query string (easy) but I want to use those tabs as filters (presentation).

If I click on a tab I want to reload the same page + url parameter (ex: test.aspx?tabFilter=1 --> click on tab 1)

I will use this parameter with my cqwp.

I'm not able to create the href in the tab name with the jquery.

The page seems to be looping...

anybody could help ?

```
<script>
 $(function() {
 var tabCount = 0;
 $(".dfwp-item div.groupheader").each(function() {
 $("#tabs ul").append("<li><a href='"+encodeURI(test.aspx?Myfilter="+$(this).text())+"'>" + $(this).text()+"</a></li>");
 $("#tabs").append("<div id='tabs-"+tabCount+"'>"+"<p>&nbsp;</p></div>");
  $(this).parent().hide();
 tabCount = tabCount+1;
 });
$("#tabs").tabs({
    select: function (e, ui) {
        window.location.href=ui.tab.href;
    }
});
 });
 </script>

<div id="tabs">
 <ul>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be malformed

```
$("#tabs ul").append("<li><a href='"+encodeURI(test.aspx?Myfilter="+$(this).text())+"'>" + $(this).text()+"</a></li>");
```

try:

```
 $("#tabs ul").append("<li><a href='"+encodeURI("test.aspx?Myfilter="+$(this).text())+"'>" + $(this).text()+"</a></li>");
```

Comment: Thank's but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution using the activate event of the tabs:

```
<script>

 $(function() {
 var tabCount = 0;
 $(".dfwp-item div.groupheader").each(function() {
$("#tabs ul").append("<li><a href='#tabs-"+tabCount+"'>" + $(this).text

()+"</a></li>");

 $("#tabs").append("<div id='tabs-"+tabCount+"'>"+"<p>&nbsp;</p></div>");
  $(this).parent().hide();
 tabCount = tabCount+1;
 });

$("#tabs").tabs({
        activate: function(event, ui){
          console.log(ui.newTab.index());
           console.log (encodeURI("test.aspx?myFilter="+ui.newTab.text()));            
           window.location.href=encodeURI("test.aspx?myFilter="+ui.newTab.text());
        },
});


 });
 </script>
```